# SwiftUI : Speech recognition works on iphone by crashes on ipad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, ios-simulator

I don't know why the app works on iphone but crashes on ipad. I am building a speech to text feature.

this is my speech to text code

```
func StartRecording() -> String{

// Configure the audio session for the app.
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try! audioSession.setCategory(.record, mode: .measurement, options: .duckOthers)
try! audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
//
let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
    self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
}

audioEngine.prepare()
try! audioEngine.start()
// Create and configure the speech recognition request.
recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else { fatalError("Unable to create a SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object") }
recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true

// Create a recognition task for the speech recognition session.
// Keep a reference to the task so that it can be canceled.
recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest) { result, error in
    var isFinal = false
    if let result = result {
        // Update the text view with the results.
        self.recognizedText = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
        isFinal = result.isFinal
    }
    if error != nil || isFinal {
        // Stop recognizing speech if there is a problem.
        self.audioEngine.stop()
        inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
        self.recognitionRequest = nil
        self.recognitionTask = nil
    }
}                   
              
 return recognizedText
}
```

the app works fine on iphone but not on ipad.
This is the error I get when I try to run speech recognition on ipad simulator

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate'

what is causing the crash and how can I fix it?

Comment: Which deployment target are you using? I ask because AVFoundation seems to have some issues running 14.0 on Xcode 12(beta).